# WSo2 WSDL Proxy Serice Error

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

Project Stage: Evaluating ESBs.

We were considering WSO2 as the ESB solution, but running into many issues.

At present I am trying to get a simple WSDL proxy service working and was not able.

These are the things I did

- Created  a WSDL Based Proxy
- Clicked on "try this service"
- Filled in the parameter (zipcode)
- Clicked Send

The response was the following

```
<TryitProxyError h:status="SOAP envelope error" xmlns:h="http://wso2.org/ns/TryitProxy">**org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Transport error: 411 Error: Length Required**</TryitProxyError>
```

**detail log**

```
[2012-08-02 10:48:21,556]  INFO - HTTPSender Unable to sendViaPost to url[http://localhost:8280/services/MYWeather.MYWeatherHttpSoap12Endpoint]
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Transport error: 411 Error: Length Required
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.handleResponse(HTTPSender.java:308)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.sendViaPost(HTTPSender.java:194)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.send(HTTPSender.java:75)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.writeMessageWithCommons(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:449)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.invoke(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:276)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:443)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:406)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:229)
    at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:165)
    at org.apache.axis2.client.ServiceClient.sendReceive(ServiceClient.java:555)
    at org.apache.axis2.client.ServiceClient.sendReceive(ServiceClient.java:531)
    at org.apache.jsp.admin.jsp.WSRequestXSSproxy_005fajaxprocessor_jsp._jspService(WSRequestXSSproxy_005fajaxprocessor_jsp.java:272)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:97)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:332)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:314)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:264)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.wso2.carbon.ui.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:161)
    at org.wso2.carbon.ui.TilesJspServlet.service(TilesJspServlet.java:80)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor.service(ContextPathServletAdaptor.java:36)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.handleRequest(ServletRegistration.java:90)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:111)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:67)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.wso2.carbon.bridge.BridgeServlet.service(BridgeServlet.java:164)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:462)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.wso2.carbon.server.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:154)
    at org.wso2.carbon.server.TomcatServer$1.invoke(TomcatServer.java:254)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:563)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:399)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProcessor.process(Http11NioProcessor.java:396)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:356)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1534)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Answer (score 2):

Does your backend web server support HTTP/1.1? If it doesn't, then that might probably be the issue here. Because, the latest version of WSO2 ESB, by default uses HTTP/1.1 for web service communication. In HTTP/1.1 it by default uses chunked Transfer-Encoding response header in place of content-length header of HTTP/1.0. Therefore you might want to either disable chunking responses or force the messages to be sent via HTTP/1.0.

Adding the following property to your ESB proxy service configuration would disable chunking.

```
<property name="DISABLE_CHUNKING" value="true" scope="axis2"/>
```

Hope it helps!

Regards,
Prabath

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Still having trouble.